# Partial view call, call Index before if not opened

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a website like this simple image

[image]
Everything in the redbox is the Index page with a default layout, the blue shows my partial view.

I have a mvc controller for emails, via a ajax actionlink i change the partial view. So you don't have to reload the complete page if you want to switch the folder.

Everything works fine if you go the follow way: 
-Click on Email in the Navbar and you comes to the Index page from Email which opens a automatic the Inbox Partial view.

This is my code in the Html to call the Inbox Partial:

```
<div id="emailBody">
     @Html.Action("EmailPartial", new { module = "1", id = "1,2"  })
</div>
```

The Partial Controller has the follow code:

```
public PartialViewResult EmailPartial(string module, string id = "1,2", int start = 0, int anzahl = 100)
        {
            if (module == "1")
            {
                List<Emailstatus> emailStati;
                List<int> TagIds = id.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                emailStati = Emailstatus.AllList().Where(x => x.Id.In(TagIds)).ToList();

                List<Emailgesendetview> emails = Emailgesendetview.AllListByBenutzerIdAndEmailStatus(benutzerId, emailStati, start, anzahl);

                if (id == "1,2")
                    ViewBag.position = 1;
                else if (id == "1")
                    ViewBag.position = 2;
                else
                    ViewBag.position = Int32.Parse(id);
                return PartialView("EmailGesendet", emails);
            }
        }
```

A click on the middle-right navigation bar triggers the follow code:

```
<li id="menu2">
            @Ajax.RawActionLink(string.Format("<i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Unread"),
            "EmailPartial",
            "Email",
            new { id = "1", module = "1", start = 0, anzahl = 100 },
            new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                AllowCache = false,
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "emailBody"
            },
            new { @class = "class"})
        </li>
```

Everything works fine.

Now i want to add some submenu items to the navbar on the left but i have no idea ( okay i have a bad one... ) how to call the index page before i call the Partialview.

Okay let me explain a litte bit more my problem...

If the user is one the Email page i could easy use the same code but if the user is on a different page (maybe support or something else) and he clicks now on the Outbox link. Now i should call the Index Email page with the outbox partial view.

So i see 2 little problems,

Before i call the Email index page, i must check on which page i am actually because i dont want to reload the complete page if i am at the Email index page with another partial view. At this moment i only want to reload the partial view with a new model. (That step is easy).
My idea to check on which page i am, is to set a "pagestatus" in my viewbag. Is there a better option?

So now if i am on a other page then Email, i cant call the partial view because i have to call the Email Index page before.

My (i think it is a bad idea) is to create different Email index pages (Index1, Index2, Index3). These Pages could have different partial view call like this:

Index1:

```
<div id="emailBody">
     @Html.Action("EmailPartial", new { module = "1", id = "1,2"  })
</div>
```

Index2:

```
<div id="emailBody">
     @Html.Action("EmailPartial", new { module = "2", id = "1"  })
</div>
```

Index3:

```
   <div id="emailBody">
         @Html.Action("EmailPartial", new { module = "3", id = "1"  })
    </div>
```

So my solution is:
Check on which page i am and if i am on a different Controller, call the Index which i need.

I think that is not a "clear" solution.

Has anyone a better solution? Creating pages for different partialview calls does not sound good...

Thank you

Comment: You are not returning a `View` from the controller method that contains the `PartialView`?

Comment: If by "Index" you mean you've left the default route as "Index" then I presume this is your main page which is displayed on the right in a layout template. Your partial view then contains the email folder contents clicked on the left nav bar. The answer will be partial views. You can have a partial view in a partial view! Look to use JQuery to perform your ajax posts to render the views. Having a partial view is so you can update the partial view "Without the parent" !!. The parent is only rendered once, which renders the partial view when it itself is requested.

Comment: I think I have not expressed myself clearly. I edited my question. Hope that clearly my question, thank you